# Render an array of React components that updates every time there is a scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am still new to react. This was my first experience with it and everything I did was learning either from here or other websites.
I am trying to understand why I cannot display an array of a react component that I created,  that automatically updates every scroll. Every time there is a scroll a section should be added, to the html.
Before going any further and putting parts of my code in this post, I want to know if this can be done.
Can I display an array of components that I have created and that update every time I use a scroll?

I have tried using React hooks like useEffect and useState. But they did not seem to work.

```
import {useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState} from "react";


//components
import {readArtworks} from "../api/artwork"
import { gsap } from "gsap";
import {Observer} from "gsap/Observer";
import ArtWorkList from "../components/ArtWorkList";



let artWorkSplit
let i = 0

const Work = () => {

 const [artworks, setArtworks] = useState([]);
 const [tl, setTl] = useState(null);
 const [skip, setSkip] = useState(0)
 const [workLists, setWorkLists] = useState([])
 const [workListsCards, setWorkListsCards] = useState([])
 let flag = true


 const ScrollHandling = () => {
    scrollerHandler.disable()
    incrementSkip()
 }

 let scrollerHandler = Observer.create({
    type: "wheel,touch,pointer",
    onUp: ScrollHandling,
    wheelSpeed: -1,
    tolerance: 2000,
    preventDefault: true,
 });


 useEffect(() => {
    fetchArtWorks();
    if(flag){
        createWorkList()
    }
    flag = false
 }, [skip]);

 const fetchArtWorks = async () => {
    const data = await readArtworks(skip)
    setArtworks([... artworks , ... data])
 }


 const incrementSkip = () => {
    setSkip(artworks.length);
 }

 const createWorkList = () => {
    i++
    let newWorkList;
    newWorkList = artWorkSplit;
    workLists.push(newWorkList)
    test()
 }

 const test = () => {
       {workLists.map((workList) => (
            workListsCards.push(<ArtWorkList  artworks={.                               workList}/> )
        ))}
 }



 if(artworks.length === 0){
     artWorkSplit = artworks.slice(0,3)
 }
 else{
    artWorkSplit = artworks.slice(artworks.length-3 ,                 artworks.length)
 }


 useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const ctx = gsap.context((self) => {
        const tl = gsap.timeline().from(".work-item", {
            duration: 2,
            stagger: 0.5,
            opacity:0
        });

        setTl(tl);
    });
    return () => ctx.revert(); // <- Cleanup!
 }, []);


return(
     <div>

         {workListsCards}

     </div>
    )
};

export default Work;
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible to modify state on a scroll event and re-render components accordingly.  Though "is it possible" questions are rarely of much use.  If you've made an attempt which isn't working as expected in some way, please update the question to include a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem and indicate what problem you are observing and what debugging you have done.